# How to connect to local Parse Server from the Parse iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

How can I connect to my locally installed Parse Server from an iOS device running the Parse iOS SDK? I've tried entering my local server's IP address but I kept getting `Network connection failed` error.

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration.applicationId = @"myAppId";
        configuration.clientKey = @"";
        configuration.server = @"http://10.0.1.26:1337";
    }]];
```

I need this for my development environment only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). If you are on Mac you can use `brew install ngrok`.

Once installed just use `ngrok http 1337` where 1337 is port number for parse-server install locally. ngrok will provide you will a randomly generated url e.g `https://8ccea37e.ngrok.io`. Update locally installed parse-server and iOS app with this url.